# KendoUI chart - how do I show animation while loading data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-chart

I have a KendoUI chart generated with JavaScript. Is there a way to clear the plotArea with a command? For the purpose of showing a "Loading..." image while waiting for a DataSource to read remote data.

Thanks

Comment: There is a complete example for this on the Telerik docs site: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/how-to/show-overlay-while-loading

Comment: I think they've included it as a part of their library now. Wasn't the case 2 years ago... Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Displaying and hiding the loading animation is:

```
// Display progress
kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), true);

// Hide progress
kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);
```

Then you should use `requestStart` and `requestEnd` events in the `DataSource` for knowing when to show or hide the progress animation.

The DataSource of the Chart would be:

```
dataSource    : {
    transport   : {
        read: {
            url:...
        }
    },
    sort        : {
        field: "year",
        dir  : "asc"
    },
    requestStart: function () {
        kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), true);
    },
    requestEnd  : function () {
        kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);

    }
},
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kcptr/

Comment: That's a neat solution! The only problem is that the loading image hangs in the middle of the page - I have several charts on the page, and so the loading image must be contained within the chart area itself: http://jsfiddle.net/ningencat/kcptr/2/ How would you go about fixing that issue? Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the container of the loading needs to have a positioning set to relative. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kcptr/3/

Comment: 3 years later and this still works perfectly. Thanks!